# Cannot select a button with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to test a web based application recording a test in Selenium IDE and have the following problem.

One of the fields (Title eg Mr, Mrs, etc.) requires the user to click a button that opens a new window with a List of Values.

When I click on the button IDE records it as `css=button.BTNimgH` and when playing back the script this error is displayed:

> [error] Element css=button.BTNimgH not found

The code for the button is:

```
<button class="BTNimg" oldclassname="BTNimg" title="List of Values" tabindex="-1" onclick="disp_lov('STDCIF','BLK_CUSTPERSONAL','PCNTRY','Country','LOV_COUNTRY','','','', '', event)">
```

And the code for the filed I need the value in is:

```
<input id="BLK_CUSTPERSONAL__TITLE" class="TXTstd" type="text" viewmode="Y" onchange="disp_auto_lov('STDCIF','BLK_CUSTPERSONAL','TITLE','Title','LOV_TITLE','','','','', this, event);" label_value="Title" title="Title" dbt="BLK_CUSTPERSONAL" dbc="TITLE" name="TITLE" dtype="VARCHAR2" size="" required="" aria-required="false" maxlength="30" tabindex="0" prevautolovval="">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the newly opened window not being selected. If you are going to interact to the elements in a new window, you need to use the `selectWindow` command.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

No Idea why it's doing it, but the locator has that extra H in it which will be causing the issue. Based on the code the locator should be

`css=button.BTNimg`